Extreme Values of an Expression with Symmetry in Sines and Cosines
I've been doing a lot of trigonometry-based sums lately, and came across this one:

I simplified this to obtain:
$$\frac{1+\sin{x}+\cos{x}}{\sin{x}\cos{x}}$$
Now, on further solving, I realized that this expression attains its minimum value when $x=45^\circ$.
It was this result that made me realize that many "maximum-minimum" value problems I've solved in the past usually end up with extreme values when $x\in\{0^\circ,45^\circ,90^\circ,215^\circ\}$, provided that the expression is symmetric in sines and cosines.
I'm preparing for a competitive entrance examination; if this statement always holds true, it could help me save a lot of valuable time while solving problems similar to the one I've shown above.
My question is, could there be an expression symmetric in $\sin{x}$ and $\cos{x}$ such that it's extreme values don't occur when $x$ lies in this set?
I've played around with graphs on Desmos to try to find a contradiction to my observation, but so far I can't find any exception.

Many trigonometric functions can be found minimised/maximised at $\pi$ which you haven’t included in your set. E.g. $\sin^3 x +\cos ^3x$.

Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial in $x$ with a root at $\alpha\in(0,0.5)$ (the "weirder" alpha is, the better; i.e. this is less likely to work at $\frac{\sqrt{2}}2$ than at $\frac{e^2}{30}$). Then consider $$f(x)=\frac1{1+(p(\cos x\sin x))^2}.$$ This will be maximised whenever $\cos x\sin x=\frac12\sin(2x)=\alpha$, which, if $\alpha$ is chosen to be sufficiently ugly, will not be at a "nice" multiple of $\pi$. Example: $$f(x)=\frac1{1+(8\sin^3x\cos^3x-20\sin^2x\cos^2x+4\sin x\cos x+1)^2}$$ is maximised at $x\approx1.12,1.715,\ldots$

As $(\sin x+\cos x)^2-1^2=2\sin x\cos x$
$$f(x)=\dfrac{\sin x+\cos x+1}{\sin x\cos x}=\dfrac2{\sin x+\cos x-1}\text{ for } \sin x+\cos x-1\ne0$$
$$\sin x+\cos x=?$$
As $\sin x+\cos x=\sqrt2\sin\left(\dfrac\pi4+x\right), 1<\sqrt2\sin\left(\dfrac\pi4+x\right)\le\sqrt2\ \ \text{for }x\in\left(0,\dfrac\pi2\right)$
$\implies1<1+\dfrac2{f(x)}\le\sqrt2\iff0<\dfrac2{f(x)}\le\sqrt2-1\iff\infty>\dfrac{f(x)}2\ge\dfrac1{\sqrt2-1}=?$
